# Error: Call to a member function store() on null when running test

Tags: php, laravel

I have written the following test:

```
public function testUserCanUploadFile()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $this->signIn();

        Storage::fake('public'); //Mock a disk
        $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('test.jpg'); //Upload a fake image.

        $assortmentAttributes = Assortment::factory()->raw(); // Use the assortment factory.
        $assortmentAttributes['image'] = $file; // Add a additional field in the assortment factory.

        $this->post(route('assortments.store'), $assortmentAttributes)->assertRedirect(); // Post the fields to the assortmentcontroller store method. Expect a 403.
        Storage::disk('public')->assertExists($file->hashName()); // Check if the field exists.

    }
```

Along with the following controller:

```
$user = request()->user();
        $assortment = $user->assortments()->create($request->all());

        /*if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            dd($request->file('image'));
        }*/
        
        Assortment::create([
             'file' => $request->file('file')->store('file', 'public')
         ]);
 
         if ($request->wantsJson()) {
             return response([], 204);
        }
        return back();
   
        return redirect()->route('assortments.show', $assortment->slug)
                        ->with('success','Verzameling is succesvol aangemaakt.');

        
    }
```

When I run the test, no file is uploaded. I just get the message: `Error: Call to a member function store() on null`. It refers to line 56 in my controller. Which is the following line:

`'file' => $request->file('file')->store('file', 'public')`

I do not go what goes wrong. This error occurred when I added this code to my controller:

```
Assortment::create([
             'file' => $request->file('file')->store('file', 'public')
         ]);
 
         if ($request->wantsJson()) {
             return response([], 204);
        }
        return back();
```

Before I added that, I did not get a error message since I used a `if` statement:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            dd($request->file('image'));
        }
```

How do I solve this error?

EDIT: solved the error. changed `file` to `image`. Now I get: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: assortments.user_id (SQL: insert into "assortments" ("slug", "updated_at", "created_at") values (-1, 2020-12-17 13:11:11, 2020-12-17 13:11:11))`

Comment: Currently you are trying to create two assortments, the first with `$user->assortments()->create()` and the second with `Assortment::create()`, the second one is missing the `user_id`.

Comment: @Remul what line?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Remul do you mean in: `Assortment::create(['image' => $request->file('image')->store('image', 'public')]);`. I forgot to put the `user_id`?

Comment: In order to fix the current error, yes, but I don't think that you want to create two assortments. Using `$user->assortments()->create($request->all())` and instead of passing `$request->all()` passing the correct request data (except the uploaded file) and adding the file path should work.

Comment: in your test  `$assortmentAttributes['image']` it should be   `$assortmentAttributes['file']` according to your controller

Comment: please read the edit @ml59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the UploadedFile under the key image

```php
$assortmentAttributes['image'] = $file;
```

And you are trying to retrieve the file with a key `file` in the controller

```php
Assortment::create([
    'file' => $request->file('file')->store('file', 'public')
]);

//Here it should be
Assortment::create([
    'file' => $request->file('image')->store('file', 'public')
]);
```

> Now I get: Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: assortments.user_id (SQL: insert into "assortments" ("slug", "updated_at", "created_at") values (-1, 2020-12-17 13:11:11, 2020-12-17 13:11:11))

You can try to create the assortment record via the relationship or manually add the value for FK `user_id`

```php
//Assuming User model has a relation defined for Assortment as assortment()
$user->assortment()->create([
    'file' => $request->file('image')->store('file', 'public')
]);

//OR
Assortment::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'file' => $request->file('image')->store('file', 'public')
]);
```

Comment: Thanks man. I already fixed that. Please read the EDIT as well.